# How to convert postgreSQL code to Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a few lines of code in postgreSQL which I would like to use to query an Oracle database with the same tables and columns.

However the postgres code isn't working in sql developer and returns an error. The code looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM file WHERE file_name IS NOT NULL 
AND file_name ~ '[\u0000-\u001f]|^$|^ | | $';
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM file WHERE file_name IS NOT NULL AND
CASE WHEN file_name LIKE '\\%' THEN right(file_name, -1) 
ELSE file_name END ~ '^[.]|[.]$';
```

I'm having trouble converting the ~ and the right(file_name, -1) parts of the code to run them in sql developer.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`right()` with a negative argument in Postgres is rather infrequently used.  But the equivalent in Oracle would be `substr(x, 2)`, so one method is:

```
SELECT *
FROM file 
WHERE file_name IS NOT NULL AND
      REGEXP_LIKE(CASE WHEN file_name LIKE '\\%' THEN substr(file_name, 2) 
                       ELSE file_name 
                  END), '^[.]|[.]$');
```

However, I would do this using a single regex in either database:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(file_name, '^(\\)?[.]|[.]$');
```

I see no advantage to use `case` when doing this type of regular expression matching.  The comparison to `NULL` is just redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Postgres's `right()` you need to use Oracle's [substr()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679)
and instead of `~` (case sensitive regular expressions like operator) the [regexp_like()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm#SQLRF00501) function with `'c'` as the 3d argument(meaning case sensitive although may be omitted):

```
SELECT * FROM file 
WHERE 
  file_name IS NOT NULL 
  AND
  REGEXP_LIKE(
    CASE 
      WHEN file_name LIKE '\\%' THEN substr(file_name, 2) 
      ELSE file_name 
    END, '^[.]|[.]$', 'c');
```